# Combinatorial Search Space - Which is the correct approach?

Tags: combinatorics

Say I draw $N$ integers in the range [1, $H$] with replacement according to some pre-specified probability distribution.

I'm interested to know the number of possible draws of length $N$ there are under this scenario. Of course, some integers will appear more often than others.

The context is in knowing the size of the search space for a local optimization algorithm I have developed.

I am conflicted between two possible combinatorial solutions:

(1) $H^N$ (permutations with repetitions)

(2) ${N+H-1}\choose{N}$=${N+H-1}\choose{H-1}$ (Stars and Bars)

The first formula arises in the context of genetic algorithms. For a binary string of length $L$, the search space size is $2^L$

The second formula arises in nonparametric bootstrapping through setting $H=N$. In this case, values are drawn uniformly with replacement.

I haven't taken a combinatorics class in a while and so feel that I might be missing a key detail.

Anyone care to weigh in here as to the correct approach ((1) or (2)) and why one approach is the correct one and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much depends on your probability distribution , if the support (i.e. the point where the prob. $>0$) is the same as the domain (i.e. in this case $[1,H]$) then you have $H^n$ possible draws if you consider the order important, otherwise ${N+H-1 \choose N} $ if you just count the number of occurences of each integer.

Instead if the support is a proper subset of the domain than the formulas are valid but you have to substitute $H$ with the cardinality of the support.

Comment: Sorry for the late activity, I have just accepted and upvoted your answer.